# mounting cifs using kerberos not getting ticket

Tags: 20.04, mount, samba, fstab, cifs

I'm trying to mount shares on Ubuntu using Kerberos authentication, after logging using an AD account, `klist` outputs the following

```
Ticket cache: FILE:/tmp/krb5cc_1320813139_Ipmgx6
Default principal: XXXX@XXX.GRP

Valid starting       Expires              Service principal
06.09.2022 14:15:58  07.09.2022 00:15:58  krbtgt/XXXX.GRP@XXX.GRP
    renew until 07.09.2022 14:15:58
```

I can also list the shares using `smbclient -k -L XXXX.com`.

I'm using this script to do the mounting:

```
#!/bin/bash


user=$(whoami)
cruid=$(whoami)
gid=$(id -g $user)
uid=$(id -u $user)

sudo mkdir /home/test
sudo mount --verbose -t cifs -o user=$user,cruid=$user,sec=krb5,gid=$gid,uid=$uid,vers=3.0 //XXX.com/XXXX /home/test
```

it outputs the following error: :q

```
mount error(126): Required key not available
```

here is a look into `/var/log/syslog`

```
Sep  6 14:21:36 anis-VM kernel: [ 8682.404967] CIFS: Attempting to mount \\XXX.com\XXX
Sep  6 14:21:36 anis-VM cifs.upcall: key description: cifs.spnego;0;0;39010000;ver=0x2;host=XXX.com;ip4=10.130.0.16;sec=krb5;uid=0x4eba0253;creduid=0x4eba0253;user=xxx@xxx.GRP;pid=0x1658
Sep  6 14:21:36 anis-VM cifs.upcall: ver=2
Sep  6 14:21:36 anis-VM cifs.upcall: host=xxxx.com
Sep  6 14:21:36 anis-VM cifs.upcall: ip=10.130.0.16
Sep  6 14:21:36 anis-VM cifs.upcall: sec=1
Sep  6 14:21:36 anis-VM cifs.upcall: uid=1320813139
Sep  6 14:21:36 anis-VM cifs.upcall: creduid=1320813139
Sep  6 14:21:36 anis-VM cifs.upcall: user=xxx@xxx.GRP
Sep  6 14:21:36 anis-VM cifs.upcall: pid=5720
Sep  6 14:21:36 anis-VM cifs.upcall: get_cachename_from_process_env: pathname=/proc/5720/environ
Sep  6 14:21:36 anis-VM cifs.upcall: get_cachename_from_process_env: cachename = FILE:/tmp/krb5cc_1320813139_Ipmgx6
Sep  6 14:21:36 anis-VM cifs.upcall: get_existing_cc: default ccache is FILE:/tmp/krb5cc_1320813139_Ipmgx6
Sep  6 14:21:36 anis-VM cifs.upcall: handle_krb5_mech: getting service ticket for xxxx.com
Sep  6 14:21:36 anis-VM cifs.upcall: cifs_krb5_get_req: unable to get credentials for xxxx.com
Sep  6 14:21:36 anis-VM cifs.upcall: handle_krb5_mech: failed to obtain service ticket (-1765328377)
Sep  6 14:21:36 anis-VM cifs.upcall: ip_to_fqdn: resolved 10.130.0.16 to xxxx.com
Sep  6 14:21:36 anis-VM cifs.upcall: handle_krb5_mech: getting service ticket for xxx.com
Sep  6 14:21:36 anis-VM cifs.upcall: cifs_krb5_get_req: unable to get credentials for xxx.com
Sep  6 14:21:36 anis-VM cifs.upcall: handle_krb5_mech: failed to obtain service ticket (-1765328377)
Sep  6 14:21:36 anis-VM cifs.upcall: Unable to obtain service ticket
Sep  6 14:21:36 anis-VM cifs.upcall: Exit status -1765328377
Sep  6 14:21:36 anis-VM kernel: [ 8682.430729] CIFS: VFS: Verify user has a krb5 ticket and keyutils is installed
Sep  6 14:21:36 anis-VM kernel: [ 8682.430771] CIFS: VFS: \\xxx.com Send error in SessSetup = -126
Sep  6 14:21:36 anis-VM kernel: [ 8682.430864] CIFS: VFS: cifs_mount failed w/return code = -126
```

I tried everything, nothing seems to fix this problem, can someone help me even with an idea?