# Mounting Home Using AutoFS and CIFS and Kerberos to Network Path

Tags: home-directory, cifs, kerberos, sssd, autofs

I am attempting to implement AutoFS on realm joined Ubuntu 22.04 LTS machines to mount the user's home path via Kerberos authentication and a SMB/CIFS share but keep hitting a wall and am uncertain what is the impediment. If I remove the AutoFS part to mount home and keep everything local, everything works without issue and logins occur normally and without issue. I then put the AutoFS in place and authentication works without issue per the PAM logs (auth.log) but the **mkhomedir_helper** shows "**permission denied**" mounting the path. *I then wait 60 seconds* (I timed it), login and it works and mounts everything without issue. I would guess there may be a timeout somewhere that I am unaware of or it is simply that the KRB5 ticket is not fully checked out/created while AutoFS is trying to do its magic so it just stops and kicks out the session. This is my guess but if that is the case, is there a method to overcome it and why 60 seconds? And if so, in what logs should I look? I am at a standstill on the issue and that is why I come here seeking expertise. Here are some details:

**/etc/auto.cifs**:

`* -fstype=cifs,rw,cruid=${UID},sec=krb5 ://PATHTOSHARE/SHARENAME/&`

**/etc/auto.master:**

`/home/LABHOME /etc/auto.cifs`

**/etc/sssd/sssd.conf:**

```
[sssd]
domains = mydomain.com
config_file_version = 2
services = nss, pam
reconnection_retries = 3

[domain/mydomain.com]
default_shell = /bin/bash
krb5_store_password_if_offline = True
cache_credentials = True
krb5_realm = MYDOMAIN.COM
realmd_tags = manages-system joined-with-adcli
id_provider = ad
fallback_homedir = /home/LABHOME/%u
ad_domain = mydomain.com
use_fully_qualified_names = False
ldap_id_mapping = True
account_cache_expiration = 2
ignore_group_members = True
access_provider = ad
krb5_ccname_template = FILE:%d/krb5cc_%U
```

**Relevant error in auth.log:**

`mkhomedir_helper: PAM unable to create create directory /home/LABHOME/username: Permission denied`

60 seconds later no such error or denial. I do have the pam_mkhomedir.so option enabled in /etc/pam.d/common-session

Comment: I believe the issue is due to the lack of a CIFS service ticket. If anyone has insight into how to properly retrieve that, I believe the issue will be solved. The issue also appears related to this one: 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1427890/mounting-cifs-using-kerberos-not-getting-ticket

Comment: I believe I may have solved this by DISABLING PAM's making of home directory and pre-populating the profile path appropriately. Still testing.

Comment: I am pretty stunned at how difficult this is proving. Despite configuring this every which way that I can come up with, it continues to fail or be hit/miss. I can configure it on one machine and it will work; I then replicate it to another machine, it fails. Sometimes it will seemingly work and the path is mounted but no permissions are granted to the path or a 'mkdir' is attempted with no success.

I would gladly appreciate any assistance or direction as I am by no means an expert in AUTOFS.

Comment: This worked fine using the above setup in the original post. The issue arose due to VMware's Horizon Agent using proprietary PAM module for the login procedure to allow credential passthrough to the desktop OS. Once this was found, I was able to determine that automating the population of the profile will not work or if it will work, it will require more knowledge than I have as well as more time. I was able to pre-populate the paths, set a script to run for all profiles at login to create symbolic links to those paths (Desktop, Documents) and move on with life.